# How to determine the time complexity of a recursive function that has a loop enclosed in it?

Tags: time-complexity, computer-science, complexity-theory

I am trying to solve LeetCode problem [143. Reorder List](https://leetcode.com/problems/reorder-list/description/):

> You are given the head of a singly linked-list. The list can be represented as:
>
> L<sub>0</sub> → L<sub>1</sub> → … → L<sub>n − 1</sub> → L<sub>n</sub>
>
> Reorder the list to be on the following form:
>
> L<sub>0</sub> → L<sub>n</sub> → L<sub>1</sub> → L<sub>n − 1</sub> → L<sub>2</sub> → L<sub>n − 2</sub> → …
>
> You may not modify the values in the list's nodes. Only nodes themselves may be changed.

This is my attempt at it:

```java
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode() {}
 *     ListNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { this.val = val; this.next = next; }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public void reorderList(ListNode head) {
        if (head == null || head.next == null || head.next.next == null) {
            return; 
        }

        ListNode n1 = head;
        ListNode temp = null;

        while (n1.next.next != null) {
            n1 = n1.next;
        }

        temp = n1.next;
        n1.next = null;
        temp.next = head.next;
        head.next = temp;

        reorderList(temp.next);
    }
}
```

I'm unable to come up with concrete reasoning for the time complexity of my code. My brain says O(n^2) but I just can't justify the why. How can the time complexity be derived?

Comment: Please do not post images of code https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI okay, apologies. fixed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my brain says O(n^2) but i just can't justify the why.

Yes, it is O(²). One execution of `reorderList` -- excluding the recursive call -- will visit all the nodes in the list in the `while` loop. So if at that moment there are  nodes in the list, this will be O(). The recursive call is made with a list that has −2 elements (since `head` and `temp` are "behind" the reference that is passed to the recursive call). This means we have a number of visits that progresses as follows:

+ −2 + −4 + ... + (1 or 2)

This is about the double of the /2 [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF), which is O(/2(/2+1)) = O(²).

#### Improving the time complexity

It is possible to solve this problem with O() time complexity. Here are some spoiler hints to get an idea how to approach it:

Hint 1:

> Could you manipulate the list so that it becomes easier to also traverse the list from its current last node *backwards*?

Hint 2:

> What is the time complexity to reverse a linked list?

Hint 3:

> Would it help to split the list into two lists?

Spoiler O() solution:

> `class Solution {
>      public ListNode getMiddle(ListNode head) {
>          ListNode fast = head.next;
>          while (fast != null && fast.next != null) {
>              head = head.next;
>              fast = fast.next.next;
>          }
>          return head;
>      }
>
>      public ListNode splitAfter(ListNode newTail) {
>          ListNode head = newTail.next;
>          newTail.next = null;
>          return head;
>      }
>
>      public ListNode reverse(ListNode head) {
>          ListNode prev = null;
>          while (head != null) {
>              ListNode next = head.next;
>              head.next = prev;
>              prev = head;
>              head = next;
>          }
>          return prev;
>      }
>
>      public void zip(ListNode head1, ListNode head2) {
>          if (head1 == null) return;
>          ListNode head = head1;
>          ListNode tail = head1;
>          while (head1 != null && head2 != null) {
>              head1 = head1.next;
>              tail = tail.next = head2;
>              head2 = head2.next;
>              tail = tail.next = head1;
>          }
>      }
>
>      public void reorderList(ListNode head) {
>          if (head != null) {
>              zip(head, reverse(splitAfter(getMiddle(head))));
>          }
>      }
>  }`